# datetime format from json to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, json, stripe-payments

I'm trying to parse the json data sent from stripe payment gateway, and the json data have the datetime encoded as a number. I tried to parse it into a proper .NET DateTime, but didnt succeed.

Can you please let me know how ?

Reproduced the json below.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# `DateTimeOffset` has `FromUnixTimeSeconds`:

```
// converts to UTC DateTimeOffset
var dtOffset = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1530291339); 

// if you need a DateTime you can
var dt = dtOffset.UtcDateTime;

// dtOffset.ToString() for example above:
// 6/29/2018 4:55:39 PM
```

DateTimeOffset also has `FromUnixTimeMilliseconds` method.  Please see [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.7.2) for more info.

The methods `FromUnixTimeSeconds` and `FromUnixTimeMilliseconds` convert the UNIX timestamp (since 01/01/1070) date to a UTC DateTimeOffset.

> The Offset property value of the returned DateTimeOffset instance is
>   TimeSpan.Zero, which represents Coordinated Universal Time.

It can be converted to the time in a specific time zone by calling the [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_TimeZoneInfo_ConvertTime_System_DateTimeOffset_System_TimeZoneInfo_) method.

Answer (score 0):

That's just the time stamp. Simply parse the date by doing `new Date(<timestamp>)`

```js
const date = new Date().getTime();
console.log(date); // <-- your number

console.log(new Date(date)); // <-- convert the timestamp to a date
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

https://stripe.com/docs/api/skus/object?lang=dotnet#sku_object-created

Comment: Hi, but I wanted it to convert into a DateTime type in C#

Comment: You would have to do the conversion manually. It doesn't look like stripe will provide that in any other format. I think @haldo's answer is what you're looking for.